How to make map view in background tappable and dragable with ScrollView on top?
The map is fixed at the top and does not move. The top of the ScrollView is transparent. When interacting with the red area — such as clicking, sliding, or zooming — you should be able to operate the map. When interacting with the bottom area, you should be able to operate the ScrollView, allowing it to scroll up and down.
The current problem is that whether you try to interact with the red area or the ScrollView, you cannot operate the MapView. Is there any way to pass events transparently through the blank area above?
I have tried using allowsHitTesting, but it is not working well. How can I properly allow interactions with the MapView through the transparent area while keeping the rest of the ScrollView functional?

The code is as bellow
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = MKMapView
    var userLatitude: String {
        return "34.052235"
    }
        
    var userLongitude: String {
        return "-118.243683"
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, colour:  .blue)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView
        var colour: UIColor

        init(_ control: MapView, colour: UIColor) {
            self.control = control
            self.colour = colour
        }

        //Managing the Display of Overlays
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            if let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
                let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline)
                polylineRenderer.strokeColor = colour
                polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 8
                return polylineRenderer
            }
            return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        view.showsUserLocation = true
        
        let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(userLatitude)!, CLLocationDegrees(userLongitude)!)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.009, longitudeDelta: 0.009)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MapView()
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .frame(height: 500)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                        Text("row \(rowIndex)")
                            .frame(height: 35)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        //.padding()
    }
}


The layout you're after is very straightforward: the map takes half the screen, the scrolling area the other half. So why complicate your life using a ZStack? Just use a Vstack and there is no need for a Rectangle():
struct MapContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack { // <-- Change ZStack to VStack
            MapView()
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                        Text("row \(rowIndex)")
                            .frame(height: 35)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

Another approach is to use an inspector sheet, which is what many apps use for similar layouts and functionality. This would give you control over the size of the scroll view and even its visibility - you could show it or hide as needed.
struct MapInspectorContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showInspector = true // <-- add a bool state to show or hide the inspector as needed (since you don't have any buttons, it's set to true here, to show automatically.

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .inspector(isPresented: $showInspector){ // <-- add .inspector modifier
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(0..<30, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                        Text("row \(rowIndex)")
                            .frame(height: 35)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.white)
                .padding()
            }
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
            .presentationDetents([.height(200), .medium])
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true) //do not allow dismissal of sheet (or comment out to allow dismissal)
            .presentationCornerRadius(30) //optional
        }
    }
}

Actually, depending on your needs, you could even use a .sheet instead of an .inspector. Look into the differences to understand which suits you better.
